# Query string in htaccess results in 404 error

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web, http-status-code-404

The goal is to redirect a query string, such as:

`mydomain.com/sheet.csv?z=abcdef`

to its respective folder, appending the query string into the folder name where the respective file is located, like so:

`mydomain.com/charts/abcdef/sheet.csv`

I tried the following but everything I tried results in a 404 error.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sheet.csv?z=([_0-9a-z-]+) /$1/sheet.csv [R]
```

**DIDN'T WORK, RESULTS IN 404 ERROR.**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^z=([_0-9a-z-]+)$    [NC]
RewriteRule sheet.csv chart/$1/sheet.csv [NC,L,R=301]
```

**DIDN'T WORK, RESULTS IN 404 ERROR.**

How can I fix this?

---

**UPDATE**

The error seems to be occurring because it is NOT redirecting but instead looking for the file:
`mydomain.com/sheet.csv` which ***does not and never will exist***.

So why is it not redirecting, and how do I fix it?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I did a bunch of trial and error experiementing. I was able to make it do SOMETHING, just need to finish getting it working.

If I do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^z=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ charts/%1/sheet.csv? [NC,L,R=301]
```

then it redirects to the url `mydomain.com/home/mydomai/public_html/mydomain/charts/abcdef/sheet.csv`

I tried every possible combination I could think of but still can't get it to just go to the URL
`mydomain.com/charts/abcdef/sheet.csv`

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot match QUERY_STRING in `RewriteRule`. Use `RewriteCond` instead and fix your regex pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)z=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sheet\.csv)/?$ /chart/%1/$1? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Make sure this rule is placed before other rules.